# Visualforce + Google Polymer

Tags: visualforce, html5

I am looking for examples which show Visualforce with Google Polymer integration. Can anyone point me to relevant links?

Answer (score 5):

The following are great sources for reference

http://www.oyecode.com/2014/10/building-bootstrap-table-using-google.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/10/chart-components-google-polymer-force-com.html

http://www.oyecode.com/2014/07/getting-started-with-google-polymer.html

https://github.com/mailtoharshit/polyforce

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the post @ [Integrating Google Polymer with VisualForce - Salesforce](http://sudipta-deb.blogspot.in/2015/01/integrating-google-polymer-with.html)

Please let me know if you need any help. Thanks.