# Using Polymer for Material Design in VisualForce Pages?

Tags: visualforce, angularjs, user-interface

I am thinking of using Google's Polymer Library to provide Material Design in apps.

[Google Polymer Library](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/)

**I have a few questions?:**

1. Is it compatible with Salesforce?
2. If yes, is there any running demo or example where I can see how exactly it is being implemented.
3. I have found this resource but this is not much helpful to me: [VisualForce + Polymer Integration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61274/visualforce-google-polymer)
   And this: [VisualForce + Google Polymer Integration Salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/10/chart-components-google-polymer-force-com.html)